# Evenly spaced grid that allows drag/drop

Tags: c#, winforms, grid

I need to create a `WinForm` application that allows the user to drag from a set of images, and position them on a grid, a tile designer of sorts.

I've tried using the `TableLayoutPanel`, however It seems to get rather slow when you have a grid 100x100, I was just wondering if there are any alternative methods out there that would allow the user to drag a tile onto the grid layout, and expand the size of the grid if they required.

Thank you.

Comment: hi, are tiles with same dimensions

Comment: @GiancarloMelis yes, all tiles are the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If tiles are contiguous, you can get the first "empty cell"

```
    private readonly Size tileSize = new Size(200, 200);
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pb = new PictureBox();
        var pt = GetEmptyCell(tileSize);
        pb.Location = pt;
        pb.Size = tileSize;
        Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    private Point GetEmptyCell(Size TileSize)
    {
        var ctrl = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        if (ctrl == null && TileSize.Width < Width && TileSize.Height < Height)
            return new Point(0, 0);

        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                ctrl = GetChildAtPoint(new Point(x, y));
                if (ctrl == null && x + TileSize.Width < Width && y + TileSize.Height < Height)
                    return new Point(x, y);

            }
        }

        throw new Exception("No Empty cells was found");
    }
```